# how to install a video component in joomla

Tags: video, joomla, components

i want to install a video component in Joomla,,,, since I am new to joomla i am finding it difficult to deal with the components can anyone help me,,, any help is appreciable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install a plugin in Joomla via the admin backend go to the menu item Extensions->Install/Unistall. Then select the component zip file usually named com_comname-1.0.zip and upload that. This should do the complete installation for you. Once done you will be able to find the component in the 'components' menu drop down.

If you looking at building a video library but wish to host your files on Vimeo, try this component [TTVideo](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/multimedia/video-players-a-gallery/13213).

Answer (score 1):

Are you uploading directly to your web server or uploading to a video service then embedding?

AllVideos is great for the latter and essentially helps you control the content and plugin environment rather than inserting a video player per se linking to a progressive download.

[AllVideo Plugin](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/multimedia/video-players-a-gallery/812)

Rather than being a "Component" this is a plugin, which allows you with a small simple script to insert into any content item. If you have collection of videos, organize the content items like any other pages and just insert the tags where necessary.

When installing a plugin, be sure to publish it prior to testing.

Comment: Joomlaworks AllVideos is the way I embed all my videos. Really simple.